# Periodic sequences of integers generated by $a_{n+1}=\frac{\operatorname{rad}(pa_{n})}{p}+\frac{\operatorname{rad}(qa_{n-1})}{q}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series, arithmetic-functions

Let's define the radical of the positive integer $n$ as
$$\operatorname{rad}(n)=\prod_{\substack{p\mid n\\ p\text{ prime}}}p$$
and consider the sequence
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{\operatorname{rad}(p\cdot a_{n})}{p}+\frac{\operatorname{rad}(q\cdot a_{n-1})}{q}$$

with $\,a_1=a_2=1\,$ and $\,p,\,q\,$ odd primes.

In some cases the sequence is cyclic, that is
$$a_{n+\tau}=a_n$$
for all $\,n\gt n_0$, being $\,\tau\,$ the cycle length.

Just two examples:

- for $\,(p,q)=(31,31),\;(n_0,\tau)=(5,207)$
- for $\,(p,q)=(5,17),\;(n_0,\tau)=(6,159)$

It is quite easy to find dozens of periodic sequences using small prime numbers: **in all cases, the length of the cycle turns out to be a multiple of 3. Is it possible to explain this singular behavior?**

Comment: It is important, that it does not suffice that (1): $a_{n+\tau}=a_n$. It is as well needed that at the same time (2) $a_{n+\tau+1}=a_{n+1}$  (at least) . It is easy to find many examples where the (1) occurs but not (2) and thus cyclicity does not occur there. See also OEIS which has the sequence for $(p,q)=(1,1)$ and also mentions that $a_n$ which occur more often than one time. (The OEIS link has been given in the MSE question on this problem.)

Comment: The MSE-question is at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4452873 and one answer of mine at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4453189 . The OEIS-link is https://oeis.org/A121369

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any odd $p$, $q$ (not necessarily prime) the values modulo $2$ follow a cycle of order 3.

Comment: Amazing answer. Such a small observation -easily provable- gives immediately the answer ... (+1)